# contextualSpellCheck installation falling for python 3.11 on Windows 11

Tags: python, spacy

I am trying to use Spell check feature within a Spacy pipeline. Their documentation states that we need to use *contextualSpellCheck* package for this([link](https://spacy.io/universe/project/contextualspellcheck/)). But when I pip-install the package the installation fails when installing editdistnace package. I am using Windows 11 with Python 3.11. The error I get is the following:

```
Building wheels for collected packages: editdistance
  Building wheel for editdistance (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [30 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\editdistance
      copying editdistance\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\editdistance
      copying editdistance\_editdistance.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\editdistance
      copying editdistance\def.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\editdistance
      running build_ext
      building 'editdistance.bycython' extension
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release
      creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\editdistance
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./editdistance "-IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\My Drive\project_files\test\include" -IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpeditdistance/_editdistance.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\editdistance/_editdistance.obj
      _editdistance.cpp
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(92): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(120): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int edit_distance_map_<1>(const int64_t *,const size_t,const int64_t *,const size_t)' being compiled
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(93): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(44): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(98): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int edit_distance_bpv<cmap_v,varr<1>>(T &,const int64_t *,const size_t &,const unsigned int &,const unsigned int &)' being compiled
              with
              [
                  T=cmap_v
              ]
      editdistance/_editdistance.cpp(120): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'unsigned int edit_distance_map_<1>(const int64_t *,const size_t,const int64_t *,const size_t)' being compiled
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I./editdistance "-IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\My Drive\project_files\test\include" -IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\include -IC:\Users\gaurav.daftary_pures\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.36.32532\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tpeditdistance/bycython.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-311\Release\editdistance/bycython.obj
      bycython.cpp
      editdistance/bycython.cpp(216): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'longintrepr.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for editdistance
  Running setup.py clean for editdistance
Failed to build editdistance
ERROR: Could not build wheels for editdistance, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I even tried installing *editdistance* separately and then installing the library but still get the same error. Has anyone else faced this issue and found a solution to this?

Comment: Switch to an older version of python, python 3.10 is probably fine.